# Get all parameter value in java

Tags: java, jquery

I am trying to get html form value parameter in to java  I am trying to get  the value of:

```
 var desc= <p>
        <img style="width: 155px;" 
        src="/test/imgSrc?file=FRXhtVWtiVVV4U3VIRzcyR3NyOE9TZA0KcDdmRDVlZklZVXYxMXlFLy9uQ2o">
        <p>
            <img style="width: 128px;">
            hello
        </p>
        <p>
            <img alt="">
        </p>
        <p></p>
    </p>
```

But I'm not getting it. I am getting half value like:

```
<p>
    hello
    <img style="width: 982px;">
</p>
<p>
    <img alt="">
</p>
<p></p>
```

I am doing like this:

```
String dec = request.getParameter("desc");
```

jsp file

```
$.post('<s:url value="/test/saveOrUpdate"/>',{desc:desc},function(data){
    console.log();
});
```

Comment: Where is desc? You know request.getParameter can be used with attribute name and definitely not on image. Revisit the tutorials and see an example of How to pass values from JSP to Java.

Comment: desc is variable  which contain  value  which is given above

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: i want to get all  value  of variable desc from jsp to  java     but   its not getting fulll value

Comment: This is not how its done. Can you show you full JSP file ?

Comment: updated jsp there

Comment: Does desc has some HTML data? Check for the double quotes, if there is any problem. You can do one more things. Try a hidden input field with and assign the value to it through document.getElementByID and keep the name attribute as desc, You can use this to get the full value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one things. Try **hidden input field**.

So, you have a field like this -

```
<input type="hidden" name="desc" id="desc" />
```

Now through Javascript assign the value of your variable desc to input field -

```
document.getElementById("desc").value=desc;
```

In java file, you can successfully use request.getParameter to get the value into string-

```
String dec = request.getParameter("desc");
```